# How Long Was It "Stately Wayne Manor?"

Tags: dc, batman, names, batman-1966

I grew up watching the US TV version of *Batman* from the 1960s (as I know many here did).  And it didn't take me long, later, to realize that series had nothing to do with the real Batman.

In that series, Bruce Wayne's home is always referred to as "Stately Wayne Manor."  (As seen here.)
[image: TV version of "stately Wayne Manor"]

Is this unique to that series?  Or has it been used in other incarnations of Batman?  And if so, when did it come into usage and when was it dropped?

Comment: What do you mean it had nothing to do with "the real Batman"? Forgive me if this is obvious, I am a whippersnapper :)

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller: Watch it, and watch recent Batman movies and read a few comics.  Note the difference in tone.  The series was played 100% for camp.  And one person saw it while growing up and hated what it did to his favorite comic book and he's the one behind all the Batman movies from the 1980s on.

Comment: @abbyhairboat: [nothing camp](http://www.comics101.com/archives/comics101/images/2003/dec10/batmite.jpg) about Batman [in the comics](https://watchusplaygames.wordpress.com/tag/1960s/), [that’s for sure](http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11/116408/2260477-batbed.png).

Comment: I've been watching CD's from the 1960's series...and I think they're Great!! I was born in 1963...and these episodes bring back so many good memories...only wish I had been a little bit older at the time. By the way, I googled the "stately Wayne manor" fom the series...and it turns out to be a noteable address in Pasadena, CA...FYI !!!

Answer (score 6):

Was it dropped? I don't think so.

The whole concept stayed similar. The significant differences (esp. appearance and things like tools) change, but that's simply due to the times changing.

The old series might look ridiculous to today's standards, but old comic versions of Batman, the Flash, etc. look ridiculous in a similar way. Some heroes got massive overhauls (e.g. Batman), others stayed the same (Spider-Man, Superman, etc.).

But even those got weird appearances on the big screen or television, e.g. watch the Spiderman movie from the 70s...

Back to Batman:
The old series was rather low budget, so there hasn't been any way to add awesome special effects or fantastic costumes (those used are still rather good for their time and they resemble the comics). E.g. the new movies depict a dark and shady Gotham, while the old series could play in pretty much any US coastal city of that time. There are significant differences, but I don't think anyone made the movies darker just because of the series being that "colorful". After all, it's still the most "accurate" comic adaption, given the available technology of the time. They added those splash screens in fighting scenes, sometimes weird camera angels similar to comics, etc. The only thing they're missing are those comic-like cuts from Hulk, but that's simply not been possible at that time.

Short version to me:
- TV series: Tried to tell stories like the comics, with costumes, abilities, tools and stories similar to comics.
- Later movies (not talking about the old/first movie): Tried to tell stories in a darker future that is believable and more serious.

Comment: Actually, the TV series was intentionally campy and silly.  Burt Ward said it was great to act because all he had to do was read the lines straight, like he was overly serious, and the kids would take it as straight and adults would laugh their heads off.  There was never any attempt to make it dark at all.  As for my question - how long was it "stately Wayne Manor," is there any chance you could answer that?  Was it used in the comics as well?  And how early and for how long?

Comment: Never really read the old comics - I know them and their style from seeing. And yes, I didn't try to say they tried to make the series dark and grim - something they certainly didn't even try. It's really colorful and got things that are simply stupid or overdone (yet alone the bat belt; just like many comics), but it's also a bit like comparing today's Star Trek with the original series. Wikipedia got an elaborative page for the Manor alone (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayne_Manor), which states they moved him to an apartment during the 60-80's plus there is a more or less complete rundown.

Comment: I'm not sure what you consider to be the "real" Batman, but if you're talking about the darker interpretation, I'd say that started some time in the 80's - although don't quote me on that.

Comment: Uh, no.  I'm talking about Batman.  Comic books and so on.  Batman was dark from the start.  Then there was the 1960s camp version aimed at kids and easy ratings.  This series bothered many fans because it was so contrary to what Batman had always been.  Then, in the 1980s, the *movies* got darker, to match what had been the case all along (except for the one TV series).

Comment: Hm, okay, I've had the impression the early comics were more "camp" and less dark/serious as well, e.g. e.g. looking at this issue: http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Issue_191 As for the series as is, I still consider it influenced by the times (and budget; i.e. a less dark version will get less restrictive ratings and stuff; something you usually don't see for comics).

Comment: I mean, that's basically the Act I cliffhanger of The Dark Knight Rises.